# Formtastic radio buttons without label of each of the radio button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, formtastic

I am using activeadmin. I need to have a radio button set with no label for the radio buttons. Like the following image [image]

```
f.input :star_rating, as: :radio, collection: (1..5), label:false
```

removes the field label, but it keeps the label for each of the radio buttons

Answer (score 2):

You can pass empty strings as labels in *collection* option:

```
f.input :star_rating,
        as: :radio,
        label: false,
        collection: [['', 1], ['', 2], ['', 3], ['', 4], ['', 5]]
```

This will render radio buttons without labels.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the member_label option

As you can call a Proc on it you could simply set the proc to return nothing, or if you want the star there, return a star...

https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic/wiki/4.1-Options-Cheat-Sheet

Comment: wow! it would be great to achieve that using member_label, will try that

Comment: Option **:member_label** is *deprecated* now. This [pull request](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic/pull/1094) explains what you should use instead.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solutions after some moments.

Here I would like to put the solution for others:

```
<%= f.input :star_rating, as: :radio, collection: (1..5).collect { |c| ['', c, {:disabled => c <=2, title: "#{c} star"}] } %>
```

To get the star images as label: (I used sass)

```
#hotel_star_rating_input li.choice {
  float: left;
  width: 30px;

  label {
    height: 25px;
    background: url('star.png') no-repeat 2px bottom;

  }
}
```